# python django web application issue - windows 10 issue

Tags: python, django

I using window 10 pro and when I learning python - web application

pip install django
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite
py manage.py runserver

This is issue, pls help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2wPx.png)

Answer (score 2):

A very common error is missing DLLs. 
Specific to your DLL. I found a link which lists the possible solutions to your problem.

https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-msvcp140-dll-is-missing/

Hope this helps. :)

**PS:** Instead of attaching an image, pasting/typing the error text would be easier for other contributors. Just my suggestion. :)

Comment: @Ng.Hau If this fixed your problem could you mark the answer as correct would help future referrers. :)

Comment: Add path in environment and move up top